# Enum toString() override

Tags: java, enums, tostring

I've been trying to get my enum of cards into strings by overriding the toString method but I keep getting all the name in uppercase, even when I entered the name in lowercase. So I tried doing a getter getName, and it keeps giving me the uppercase name. Am I doing something wrong? Because it is working with another enum I'm using.

```
public enum Color {
    HEART ("♥"), //previously "heart"
    DIAMOND ("♦"), //previously "diamond"
    CLOVER ("♣"), //previously "clover"
    SPADE ("♠"), //previously "spade"
    NA ("NA");

    private String name;


    private Color(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name();
    }

};
```

Comment: You're not overriding `toString` - what makes you think you are? You should have `@Override public String toString() { return name; }`

Comment: In your getName method, you should be doing this.name not this.name()

Comment: @Jon Skeet is was actually just the syntax error people made me notice. Tbh I wonder why it didn't warn me about it because no method name() exists but it still runs as if.

Comment: The name() method does exist - that was your problem.

Comment: @cppbeginner: `name()` is inherited from `Enum`. Note that if you'd provided a [mcve] from the start, we'd have been able to solve this very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
public String getName() {
        return this.name();
    }
```

To this:

```
public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I'm a dumb ass. How often do I miss such syntax error and waste so much time noticing them.

Comment: @AltanRapsied: It wasn't a syntax error - if it had been, it wouldn't have compiled. It was a logic error, because you called the `name()` method instead of using the `name` field which is what you wanted.